# Sum of each two elements using vector functions

Tags: kdb, k

How to get sum of eath two elements with the vector functions? I want the same result as:

```
{x+y}':[1 2 3 2 1]
```

Why this approach gives something different than first one?

```
sum':[1 2 3 2 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sum` is not the same as `{x+y}`.

`sum` has rank 1 meaning it takes one input and sums the elements of that input.

It can sum an atom:

```
q)sum 1
1
```

a uniform list

```
q)sum 1 2
3
```

or a list of lists

```
q)sum(1 2;3 4)
4 6
```

`{x+y}` is rank 2 meaning it requires two inputs.

```
q){x+y}[1;2]
3
q){x+y}[1 2;3 4]
4 6
```

Giving it an atom, a single list, or a list of lists leads to projections

```
q){x+y}1
{x+y}[1]
q){x+y}1 2
{x+y}[1 2]
q){x+y}(1 2;3 4)
{x+y}[(1 2;3 4)]
```

Since each-prior (`':`) creates binary pairs from the input and attempts to apply a rank 2 function, it works as intended on your rank 2 function `{x+y}`.

But since `sum` is not rank 2 the each-prior doesn't generate pairs in the same way, it's equivalent to doing

```
q){x}':[1 2 3 2 1]
1 2 3 2 1
q){sum x}':[1 2 3 2 1]
1 2 3 2 1
```

You could force it to be rank 2:

```
q){sum(x;y)}':[1 2 3 2 1]
1 3 5 5 3
```

but this gives a different result since `sum` ignores nulls while `+` doesn't.

```
q)sum(0N;1)
1
q)0N+1
0N
```

Finally, an alternative way to achieve this using sum (and without using each-prior) is to shift the vector using `prev` and then sum

```
q){sum(prev x;x)}[1 2 3 2 1]
0N 3 5 5 3
```

Comment: Just get it that `sum` acts as v1 forcing `':` to act as each-parallel rather than each-prior. Thank you, Terry!

Comment: Yes, good point! That explains it better than I did ha